# TensorFlow dataset collapses with too much data

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I'm using the simplest model available to make this testcase in Node.js:

```js
  model = tf.sequential();
  model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1, inputShape: [1]}));
```

And training it with a formula `X+X=Y` for testing purposes:

```
  let xsData = [];
  let ysData = [];
  for (let i = 1; i < 17; i++) { // Please note the 16 iterations here!
    xsData.push(i);
    ysData.push(i+i);
  }

  const xs = tf.tensor2d(xsData, [xsData.length, 1]);
  const ys = tf.tensor2d(ysData, [ysData.length, 1]);

  await model.fit(xs, ys, {epochs: 500});
```

After that completes, I'm testing the model using the number ten:

```js
  model.predict(tf.tensor2d([10], [1, 1])).dataSync();
```

Which gives me a value of *around 20*. Which is correct (10+10=20).

Now for **the problem**: Whenever I change the iterations to 17+, the model collapses. I test the same number (10), output results in `-1.9837386463351284e+25` and such. Even higher dataset iterations result in `Infinity` and `NaN`.

Does anyone have a clue what is going on here? Would be great if anyone could point me in the right direction. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried different optimizers?

Comment: @Frightera - Thank you! You hit the jackpot. I was using SGD, have tried rmsprop now. That seems to give me the best results, even with 5000 iterations in the for-loop. Would you mind posting this as an answer? I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: Thank you too, added an answer with explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using SGD in regression could be tricky as **outputs don't have an upper bound** and that can lead `NaN` values in loss, in other words exploding gradients etc.

Changing optimizer to `Adam` or `RMSProp` works most of the times.